# how can i convert this string which is json response in java collection?

Tags: java, json, parsing, collections, gson

I have a string in my servlet in java as a json response. how can i get it as list or in any sort of collection. I need to create a csv from this. Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
"[{\"subscriptiontypecode\":\"ELEC\",\"subscriptiontypename\":\"Electricity Billing\",\"billgroupcode\":\"ELEC\",\"billgroupname\":\"Default\",\"billcyclecode\":\"201308\",\"billcyclename\":\"August,2013\",\"unitcode\":\"VGU0000100\",\"unitname\":\"T1/001\",\"totalcharge\":\"2809.00\",\"charge_DHBVNENERGY\":\"1720.00\",\"charge_DGENERGY\":\"233.00\",\"charge_DHBVNMMC\":\"0.00\",\"charge_CAECHARGES\":\"856.00\",\"charge_INTEREST\":\"0.00\",\"charge_ARREARS\":\"0.00\"},{\"subscriptiontypecode\":\"ELEC\",\"subscriptiontypename\":\"Electricity Billing\",\"billgroupcode\":\"ELEC\",\"billgroupname\":\"Default\",\"billcyclecode\":\"201307\",\"billcyclename\":\"July,2013\",\"unitcode\":\"VGU0000100\",\"unitname\":\"T1/001\",\"totalcharge\":\"2566.00\",\"charge_DHBVNENERGY\":\"1699.00\",\"charge_DGENERGY\":\"274.00\",\"charge_DHBVNMMC\":\"0.00\",\"charge_CAECHARGES\":\"593.00\",\"charge_INTEREST\":\"0.00\",\"charge_ARREARS\":\"0.00\"}]\n"
```

Comment: You could also just create a `new JSONObject()` (if it is a valid one), loop through it and assign the values to a Map

Comment: Is this string from your code or is this real response because in this form it is not valid JSon?

Comment: @Pshemo     its valid json. I can able to parse against the List of Maps.

Comment: @Prabhakaran As a literal written in code it is valid JSon, but if you would write this in file and try to parse it you would have some problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String json = "[{\"subscriptiontypecode\":\"ELEC\",\"subscriptiontypename\":\"Electricity Billing\",\"billgroupcode\":\"ELEC\",\"billgroupname\":\"Default\",\"billcyclecode\":\"201308\",\"billcyclename\":\"August,2013\",\"unitcode\":\"VGU0000100\",\"unitname\":\"T1/001\",\"totalcharge\":\"2809.00\",\"charge_DHBVNENERGY\":\"1720.00\",\"charge_DGENERGY\":\"233.00\",\"charge_DHBVNMMC\":\"0.00\",\"charge_CAECHARGES\":\"856.00\",\"charge_INTEREST\":\"0.00\",\"charge_ARREARS\":\"0.00\"},{\"subscriptiontypecode\":\"ELEC\",\"subscriptiontypename\":\"Electricity Billing\",\"billgroupcode\":\"ELEC\",\"billgroupname\":\"Default\",\"billcyclecode\":\"201307\",\"billcyclename\":\"July,2013\",\"unitcode\":\"VGU0000100\",\"unitname\":\"T1/001\",\"totalcharge\":\"2566.00\",\"charge_DHBVNENERGY\":\"1699.00\",\"charge_DGENERGY\":\"274.00\",\"charge_DHBVNMMC\":\"0.00\",\"charge_CAECHARGES\":\"593.00\",\"charge_INTEREST\":\"0.00\",\"charge_ARREARS\":\"0.00\"}]\n";


   JSONArray jsonArray =  JSONArray.fromObject( json);
   Collection<Map<String,String>> collection = JSONArray.toCollection(jsonArray, HashMap.class);                          
   for (Iterator iterator = collection.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
          Map<String, String> mapObject = (Map<String,String>) iterator.next();
          System.out.println("------------Starting one record------");
          System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
          for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry:mapObject.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() +" =  " +entry.getValue());
          }
          System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
    }
```

**OutPut**

```
------------Starting one record------
--------------------------------------
billgroupname =  Default
charge_DHBVNMMC =  0.00
unitcode =  VGU0000100
unitname =  T1/001
charge_INTEREST =  0.00
charge_ARREARS =  0.00
billgroupcode =  ELEC
subscriptiontypecode =  ELEC
charge_DGENERGY =  233.00
subscriptiontypename =  Electricity Billing
charge_CAECHARGES =  856.00
totalcharge =  2809.00
charge_DHBVNENERGY =  1720.00
billcyclecode =  201308
billcyclename =  August,2013
--------------------------------------
------------Starting one record------
--------------------------------------
billgroupname =  Default
charge_DHBVNMMC =  0.00
unitcode =  VGU0000100
unitname =  T1/001
charge_INTEREST =  0.00
charge_ARREARS =  0.00
billgroupcode =  ELEC
subscriptiontypecode =  ELEC
charge_DGENERGY =  274.00
subscriptiontypename =  Electricity Billing
charge_CAECHARGES =  593.00
totalcharge =  2566.00
charge_DHBVNENERGY =  1699.00
billcyclecode =  201307
billcyclename =  July,2013
--------------------------------------
```

If you have any doubt on this let me know......

Answer (score 1):

Consider [Google GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library.

It will help you to solve your task to parse this JSON to a collection of java objects.

Answer (score 1):

search for these and you will get them: 
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your custom Class as per your JSON response and then user [google GSON liberay](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)